# How to fill NaN values based on the top and bottom strings with highest frequency

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, missing-data

I have a `dataframe` of string values with missing values in it. It needs to be populated/filled by the below conditions.

- From the `NaN` value index , Check the last 3 rows and next 3 rows and replace the `NaN` with the most frequent/repeated value out of 6 rows.
- If there is 2 strings with an equal amount of frequency occurred from the last 3 rows and next 3 rows , replace the `NaN` with the value that has lowest index out of theses 6 rows.

My `DataFrame`:

```
     reading
0       talk
1       kill
2        NaN
3   vertical
4       type
5       kill
6        NaN
7   vertical
8   vertical
9       type
10   durable
11       NaN
12   durable
13  vertical
```

Expected output:

```
     reading
0       talk
1       kill
2       kill
3   vertical
4       type
5       kill
6   vertical
7   vertical
8   vertical
9       type
10   durable
11  vertical
12   durable
13  vertical
```

Here is the minimum reproducible code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'reading':['talk','kill',np.NAN,'vertical','type','kill',np.NAN,'vertical','vertical','type','durable',np.NAN,'durable','vertical']}) 

def filldf(df):
    # Do the logic here
    return df
```

I am not sure how to approach this problem. Any help will be appreciated !!

Comment: the logic is unclear, please detail

Comment: Basically, the NaN should be filled based on the top 3 values and bottom 3 values from the NaN index and I have added condition for that.

Comment: Do you mean "last 3 rows" and "next 3 rows" from the row of NaN?  For example, if NaN appears in row 5, you want to see values from row 2 - row 4 and row 6 - row 8?  Then find the most frequent values within those 6 rows?

Comment: Exactly @Emma . You are right.

Comment: "First" and "Last" is still confusing.  Please edit with "last 3 rows and next 3 rows from a NaN row".

Comment: Updated my question @Emma . Sorry for the poor communication

Comment: What is the size of the DataFrame? I think this would be hard to vectorize efficiently. You can use pd.Series.rolling and get the most common occurrence for each window then use the resulting Series to fill the NaNs but getting the most common occurrence for each window would be inefficient. I think you are better off implementing your own logic with a for loop here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have too many NaN values, you can iterate over the index of NaN "reading" values and simply look for the [`mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) of the surrounding 6 values of it (use `iloc` to get the first occurrence of multiple modes) and assign the values back to the corresponding "NaN" values

```
msk = df['reading'].isna()
df.loc[msk, 'reading'] = [df.loc[min(0, i-3):i+3, 'reading'].mode().iloc[0] for i in  df.index[msk]]
```

Output:

```
     reading
0       talk
1       kill
2       kill
3   vertical
4       type
5       kill
6   vertical
7   vertical
8   vertical
9       type
10   durable
11  vertical
12   durable
13  vertical
```